# Mapping of String to Type

Tags: scala, reflection, types

I am currently trying to write a method that takes a JSON (what API does not matter here) and validates it. I want the method to look something like this:

`def validateJson(json, expectedType: Map[String, Type(?)], allowedVals: Map[String, Seq[expectedType(key)]]): Boolean`

**The problem is:** I do have a method `jsonfield.validate[expectedType]` but I do not know how to pass an unknown number of useable type parameters associated with strings to a method.

I'd gladly use some runtime reflection if that is possible here, or any advanced feature necessary to make this work easily. Any suggestions appreciated.

PS: I am using Play Framework 2.6.3

**Edit:** 
I am trying to use the passed types like this

```
val allowed = allowedVals(field) // a Set
// if field contents contained in allowed value set...
if( allowed(field.validate[expectedType(field)].get) ) foo
```

Comment: Rather use a sealed family

Answer (score 1):

<strike>Maybe you can use [varargs](https://alvinalexander.com/scala/scala-varargs-syntax-function-examples) in runtime or [abstract over arity](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/wiki/Feature-overview:-shapeless-2.0.0#facilities-for-abstracting-over-arity) in compile time or just use an HList:</strike>

```
def foo[L <: HList](l: L) = ???

trait A
trait B
trait C
val a: A = new A {}
val b: B = new B {}
val c: C = new C {}

foo[A :: B :: C :: HNil](a :: b :: c :: HNil)
```

---

Sounds like you're looking for [dependent type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependent_type)/dependent function/[polymorphic function](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/wiki/Feature-overview:-shapeless-2.0.0#polymorphic-function-values):

```
import shapeless.Poly1
import shapeless.syntax.singleton._

object expectedTypeAndValue extends Poly1 {
  implicit val aCase: Case.Aux["a", Int] = at["a"](_ => 1)
  implicit val bCase: Case.Aux["b", Long] = at["b"](_ => 2L)
  implicit val cCase: Case.Aux["c", Double] = at["c"](_ => 3.0)
}

def validateJson(json: Json): Boolean = {
  val x: Long = expectedTypeAndValue["b"]("b".narrow)
  ???
}
```

in [Typelevel Scala](https://github.com/typelevel/scala) or

```
import shapeless.{Poly1, Witness}
import shapeless.syntax.singleton._

object expectedTypeAndValue extends Poly1 {
  implicit val aCase: Case.Aux[Witness.`"a"`.T, Int] = at[Witness.`"a"`.T](_ => 1)
  implicit val bCase: Case.Aux[Witness.`"b"`.T, Long] = at[Witness.`"b"`.T](_ => 2L)
  implicit val cCase: Case.Aux[Witness.`"c"`.T, Double] = at[Witness.`"c"`.T](_ => 3.0)
}

def validateJson(json: Json): Boolean = {
  val x: Long = expectedTypeAndValue[Witness.`"b"`.T]("b".narrow)
  ???
}
```

in Lightbend Scala (ordinary Scala).

---

You can create also custom type class:

```
  trait ExpectedTypeAndVals[S <: String] {
    type Out
    def apply(s: S): Set[Out]
  }

  object ExpectedTypeAndVals {
    type Aux[S <: String, Out0] = ExpectedTypeAndVals[S] {type Out = Out0}

    implicit def mkExpectedTypeAndVals[S <: String]: ExpectedTypeAndVals.Aux[S, ???] =
      new ExpectedTypeAndVals[S] {
        override type Out = ???
        override def apply(s: S): Set[Out] = ???
      }
  }

  def allowed[S <: String, Out](json: Json)(implicit
                                            typeAndVals: ExpectedTypeAndVals.Aux[S, Out]
  ): Boolean = {
    val str: S = ???
    val set: Set[Out] = typeAndVals(str)
    ???
  }

  if(allowed(json)) {
    ???
  }
```

Comment: This sounds like I'd have an association between Types and Strings via positions in Lists, which is less than optimal. But shapeless sounds like the right direction. Any idea on how to get the association?

Comment: Adding a quick explanation or a useful reference for beginners (or both) would be amazing, thanks!

Comment: @Dracam
This is the link I've already recommended: https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/wiki/Feature-overview:-shapeless-2.0.0#polymorphic-function-values
Also I would recommend pdf https://github.com/underscoreio/shapeless-guide/blob/develop/dist/shapeless-guide.pdf (chapters 4.1 "Dependent types", 4.2 "Dependently typed functions").

Comment: Is it possible to shorten the shapeless features for something like `Map("value" ->at["a"](_ => 1) )` or anything? Creating an extra object for every validation is actually even worse than to always validate by hand.

Comment: I edited the question to clarify what I want to accomplish - easily casting field contents to the type they should have if present and then checking whether it's in the allowed list.

Comment: @Dracam You should specify (or calculate) somehow what type corresponds to a string and what set of elements of that type corresponds to the string. To do so you create an object extending Poly1 or your own type class or calculate this somehow else but anyway you should specify or calculate that. If the rules are the same it's enough to have one object or one type class, if the rules can change you need several. Shapeless is built on macros and implicits (and type classes use implicits as well). So you have to use implicits. I updated my answer.